# What is the easiest way to rotate an image in Xamarin Forms using MVVM with Prism

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, rotation, prism

what is the easiest way to for example rotate an image by 180 degrees when clicking the image with a command from the ViewModel? I am using Prism.

Since there is also some Logic behind the click, I've tried mixing it up with a Gesture Regognizer and an event handler, but that does not work well together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new property in your viewmodel to indicate whether the image should be rotated:

```cs
private bool _showImageRotated;
public bool ShowImageRotated
{
    get => _showImageRotated;
    set => SetProperty(ref _showImageRotated, value);
}
```

Then, in your XAML code you can bind this property to the property `Rotation` of your `Image` element using a converter from boolean to double – the `Rotation` property [expects the degrees of the rotation as a double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.rotation?view=xamarin-forms).

To do so, define a new converter:

```cs
public class BooleanToDegreesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? 180 : 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Register this new converter inside your `App.xaml` file:

```xml
<converters:BooleanToDegreesConverter x:Key="BooleanToDegrees" />
```

And then use it to bind the `Rotation` property of your image to the new boolean property you have defined in your viewmodel:

```xml
<Image
    ...
    Rotation="{Binding ShowImageRotated, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToDegrees}}"
    ... />
```

After doing this, your image will appear either rotated or normal depending on the value of the property `ShowImageRotated`.

#### Approach 2: Rotate image with animation

Instead of creating and using a converter, you can rotate your image using an animation by adding this to the code behind of your view:

```cs
private YourViewModel _viewModel;

...

protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
{
    base.OnBindingContextChanged();

    if (_viewModel != null)
    {
        _viewModel.PropertyChanged -= OnViewModelPropertyChanged;
    }

    _viewModel = BindingContext as YourViewModel;

    if (_viewModel != null)
    {
        // Subscribe to the viewmodel property changes to know when to start 
        // the rotation
        _viewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;

        // Set the intial rotation angle
        YourImage.Rotation = _viewModel.ShowImageRotated ? 180 : 0;
    }
}

private void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case nameof(YourViewModel.ShowImageRotated):
            // If the property ShowImageRotated changes, start the animation
            RotateImageWithAnimation();
            break;
    }
}

private void RotateImageWithAnimation()
{
    if (_viewModel != null)
    {
        var startAngle = _viewModel.ShowImageRotated ? 0 : 180;
        var endAngle = _viewModel.ShowImageRotated ? 180 : 0;
        new Animation(v => YourImage.Rotation = v, startAngle, endAngle).Commit(this, "Image rotation");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, i tried your first approach since I already use this kind of a boolean property already. Worked in my first try and I needed minimum effort. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You may find Dave Britch's Behaviours Library useful for this. It's described in his blog here:

https://www.davidbritch.com/2016/07/xamarinforms-behaviors-rotateaction.html

A snip from his blog:

*The following code example demonstrates using the EventHandlerBehavior and RotateAction classes to implement a compound animation that concurrently rotates an Image control on the X, Y, and Z axes:*

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="monkey.png" Opacity="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
<Button Text="Run Animation">
    <Button.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior EventName="Clicked">
            <!-- Compound Animation -->
            <behaviors:RotateAction TargetObject="{x:Reference image}" 
                                    Duration="600000" 
                                    FinalAngle="110520" />
            <behaviors:RotateAction TargetObject="{x:Reference image}" 
                                    Duration="600000" 
                                    FinalAngle="90360" 
                                    Axis="X" />
            <behaviors:RotateAction TargetObject="{x:Reference image}" 
                                    Duration="600000" 
                                    FinalAngle="71640" 
                                    Axis="Y" />
        </behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior>
    </Button.Behaviors>
</Button>
```